# Datomic table model

Tags: datomic

I have an application that requires a database containing a set of products where each product can have a set of tables. The end-user should be able to add new products and define new tables for a product. So each table has a set of columns that are specified by the user. The user can then fill the tables with rows of data. Each table belongs to exactly one product.

The end-user should also be able to view the tables as they were at a specific point in time (at a certain transaction).

How would I go about making a schema for this in Datomic so that querying it would be as efficient as possible?

Comment: I personally would need to see examples before I can answer this question, especially since 'table' is such an overloaded term in the database world.

Comment: A table in this question is the same as a table in an SQL database. It is defined by a set of columns and have rows of data. [Here](http://www.teach-ict.com/gcse_new/databases/terminology/miniweb/images/table.gif) is one example of such a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with 4 entity types: products, tables, columns, and rows.

The relationship between products and tables is best handled by a `:table/product` to-one ref attribute, but a `:product/tables` to-many component ref attribute could also work (the latter does not enforce the one-to-many relationship).

Likewise, I would use either a `:column/table` or `:table/columns` attribute. I would also have a `:column/name` string attribute and maybe a `:column/type` enumerated attribute.

The hardest part is to model rows.

One tempting solution is to just create an attribute per column - I actually think it's bad idea, Datomic attributes are not intended for such a dynamic use. In particular, schema attributes are stored in a cache on the Peer that's not meant to grow big. (I may be wrong about this, so it'd be nice if someone in the Datomic team could confirm.)

Instead, I would have a few dozens reusable `:row/cell-0`, `:row/cell-1`, `:row/cell-2`, etc. 'cell position' attributes, that are shared across all tables. Each actual column would be mapped to a  at creation time by a to-one `:column/position` attribute.

If the rows can have several data types, it's a bit more difficult, you'd have to basically make an attribute for each (type,position) pair.

Then each row basically consist of a `:row/table` attribute and the above cell position attributes.

Here's a Datalog query that would let you read the whole table

```
[:find ?row ?column-name ?val :in $ ?table :where
 [?column :column/table ?table]
 [?row :row/table ?table]
 [?row ?pos ?val]
 [?column :column/position ?pos]
 [?column :column/name ?column-name]]
```

Note that all of the above is only useful if you want to query the table with Datalog directly against your Datomic db. But it can be also completely fine to serialize your tables and store them as blobs - especially if they're small; later, you pull out the blob, deserialize it, then you can query with Datalog too. And if tables are to coarse for this use, maybe you can do it with rows.

Comment: Modelling the rows was exactly what I got stuck on, thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @valentin-waeselynck you can have about 1 million schema objects, attributes, partitions, functions etc. After that Datomic will reject anything you try to transact which would require an additional schema identifier, i.e. entity IDs in the :db.part/db partition span from 0 to 1048575. This is the only limit.